# News: Single-view page in category does not work

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

TYPO3 9.5, news 7.1: 
i defined in the news categories pages with news plugins for the single views. The list view contains many categories and the single news should show up on the different pages which are defined in the categories. But this does not work: all news are shown on the page which is defined in the flexform of the list plugin. The categories does not overwrite the entry in the flexform.

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the default typoscript
detailPidDetermination = flexform, categories, default

This defines the order, change it and set categories first